# how to combine following two queries to one result?

Tags: sql, union

I have two queries.

I want to combine them together as one result. they have `prfa_type` as common ID.

First query returns 18 result, second query returns 4 result.

I want to combine them so it will give 18 results, combined.

First Query:

```
SELECT prfa_nametr, 
   prfa_type, 
   Sum(orit_quantity) AS Miktar, 
   Sum(CASE 
         WHEN orit_currencyid = 1 THEN orit_sumnetamount - 
                                       orit_sumnetamount * 
                                       oram_discountrate 
         WHEN orit_currencyid = 2 THEN orit_sumnetamount * 2 - 
                                       orit_sumnetamount * oram_discountrate 
                                       * 2 
         WHEN orit_currencyid = 3 THEN orit_sumnetamount * 3 - 
                                       orit_sumnetamount * oram_discountrate 
                                       * 3 
         WHEN orit_currencyid = 4 THEN orit_sumnetamount * 4 - 
                                       orit_sumnetamount * oram_discountrate 
                                       * 4 
       END)           AS Toplam 
FROM   orderitem_crt 
   INNER JOIN product_crt 
           ON orit_productid = prod_id 
   INNER JOIN productfamily_crt 
           ON prod_productfamilyid = prfa_id 
   INNER JOIN order_crt 
           ON orit_orderid = orde_id 
   INNER JOIN orderamount_crt 
           ON oram_orderid = orde_id 
WHERE  orit_sumnetamount <> 0 
   AND orit_alternativeno = 0 
   AND orde_deleted IS NULL 
   AND orde_stageid <> 5 
   AND orit_deleted IS NULL 
GROUP  BY prfa_nametr, 
      prfa_type 
ORDER  BY prfa_nametr </i>
```

second query:

```
SELECT prfa_type, 
   Sum(orit_quantity) AS Miktar, 
   Sum(CASE 
         WHEN orit_currencyid = 1 THEN orit_sumnetamount - 
                                       orit_sumnetamount * 
                                       oram_discountrate 
         WHEN orit_currencyid = 2 THEN orit_sumnetamount * 2 - 
                                       orit_sumnetamount * oram_discountrate 
                                       * 2 
         WHEN orit_currencyid = 3 THEN orit_sumnetamount * 3 - 
                                       orit_sumnetamount * oram_discountrate 
                                       * 3 
         WHEN orit_currencyid = 4 THEN orit_sumnetamount * 4 - 
                                       orit_sumnetamount * oram_discountrate 
                                       * 4 
       END)           AS Toplam 
FROM   orderitem_crt 
   INNER JOIN product_crt 
           ON orit_productid = prod_id 
   INNER JOIN productfamily_crt 
           ON prod_productfamilyid = prfa_id 
   INNER JOIN order_crt 
           ON orit_orderid = orde_id 
   INNER JOIN orderamount_crt 
           ON oram_orderid = orde_id 
WHERE  orit_sumnetamount <> 0 
   AND orit_alternativeno = 0 
   AND orde_deleted IS NULL 
   AND orde_stageid <> 5 
   AND orit_deleted IS NULL 
GROUP  BY prfa_type 
ORDER  BY prfa_type
```

Comment: @Horaciux, OP notes that when the 18 and 4 rows are combined, there should be 18 rows.

Comment: @paqogomez that right, I misread request.

Comment: Looking at the queries what are you trying to do here? Why do you want to combine the results?

Comment: @Horaciux, I already tried to use union but it raises error: All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists...

Comment: first query evaluates the sum  according to prfa_ID,second query  sums the totals of prfa_ID according to prfa_type.

Comment: I didnt get what you mean with combined. The result sets are different. Combine what? You want the toplam per prfa_type shows beside all records in the first result set where you have prfa_nametr?

Comment: @user3252936 but what kind of combination? 18 + 4 = 22 records, that what an `UNION ALL` will give you, but you said 18 + 4 combined = 18. If you need 22 record combined, you need to add an empty field in second querry. Or do you need sum results when `prfa_type` is the same?

Comment: @horaciux no no no...   not 18+4... 4 results has to be extra to each 18 results...     18 ones already have prfa_type, 4 ones have prfa_type each, becaouse grouped by prfa_type...sum in first quert returns sum according to prfa_name, which has count 18, sum in second query  returns sum according to prfa_Type, which has count of 4 ......

Comment: @user3252936 could you add both queries resultset and expected final result set? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few ways of doing this, if you stick  everything in query1 into a temporary table, then do the same for query2, you could be able to execute the following query

```
select query1.prfa_nametr,
  query1.prfa_type,
  query1.Miktar,
  query1.Toplam,
  query2.Miktar,
  query2.Toplam
from #TempTableForQuery1 as query1
left join #TempTableForQuery2 as query2 
  on query1.prfa_type = query2.prfa_type
order by query1.prfa_nametr
```

You can also get away by doing something more messy, like

```
from (entire content of query 1) as query1
join (entire content of query 2) as query2 on ...
```

There are other ways that are less messy, but probably a bit more complicated.

-Update- Complete code requested, complete code given below (notice the into's before the from clause, this creates the temporary tables for us). You should be able to copy paste everything below into management studio and execute.

`--first query
SELECT prfa_nametr, 
   prfa_type, 
   Sum(orit_quantity) AS Miktar, 
   Sum(CASE 
         WHEN orit_currencyid = 1 THEN orit_sumnetamount - 
                                       orit_sumnetamount * 
                                       oram_discountrate 
         WHEN orit_currencyid = 2 THEN orit_sumnetamount * 2 - 
                                       orit_sumnetamount * oram_discountrate 
                                       * 2 
         WHEN orit_currencyid = 3 THEN orit_sumnetamount * 3 - 
                                       orit_sumnetamount * oram_discountrate 
                                       * 3 
         WHEN orit_currencyid = 4 THEN orit_sumnetamount * 4 - 
                                       orit_sumnetamount * oram_discountrate 
                                       * 4 
       END)           AS Toplam 
into #TempTableForQuery1
FROM   orderitem_crt 
   INNER JOIN product_crt 
           ON orit_productid = prod_id 
   INNER JOIN productfamily_crt 
           ON prod_productfamilyid = prfa_id 
   INNER JOIN order_crt 
           ON orit_orderid = orde_id 
   INNER JOIN orderamount_crt 
           ON oram_orderid = orde_id 
WHERE  orit_sumnetamount <> 0 
   AND orit_alternativeno = 0 
   AND orde_deleted IS NULL 
   AND orde_stageid <> 5 
   AND orit_deleted IS NULL 
GROUP  BY prfa_nametr, 
      prfa_type 
--second query
SELECT prfa_type, 
   Sum(orit_quantity) AS Miktar, 
   Sum(CASE 
         WHEN orit_currencyid = 1 THEN orit_sumnetamount - 
                                       orit_sumnetamount * 
                                       oram_discountrate 
         WHEN orit_currencyid = 2 THEN orit_sumnetamount * 2 - 
                                       orit_sumnetamount * oram_discountrate 
                                       * 2 
         WHEN orit_currencyid = 3 THEN orit_sumnetamount * 3 - 
                                       orit_sumnetamount * oram_discountrate 
                                       * 3 
         WHEN orit_currencyid = 4 THEN orit_sumnetamount * 4 - 
                                       orit_sumnetamount * oram_discountrate 
                                       * 4 
       END)           AS Toplam 
into #TempTableForQuery2
FROM   orderitem_crt 
   INNER JOIN product_crt 
           ON orit_productid = prod_id 
   INNER JOIN productfamily_crt 
           ON prod_productfamilyid = prfa_id 
   INNER JOIN order_crt 
           ON orit_orderid = orde_id 
   INNER JOIN orderamount_crt 
           ON oram_orderid = orde_id 
WHERE  orit_sumnetamount <> 0 
   AND orit_alternativeno = 0 
   AND orde_deleted IS NULL 
   AND orde_stageid <> 5 
   AND orit_deleted IS NULL 
GROUP  BY prfa_type 
--joining query
select query1.prfa_nametr,
  query1.prfa_type,
  query1.Miktar,
  query1.Toplam,
  query2.Miktar,
  query2.Toplam
from #TempTableForQuery1 as query1
left join #TempTableForQuery2 as query2 
  on query1.prfa_type = query2.prfa_type
order by query1.prfa_nametr
--drop temp tables
drop table #TempTableForQuery1
drop table #TempTableForQuery2`

Comment: @horaciuz  resultset for q1 : http://postimg.org/image/ek5ifhall/  resultset for q2 :http://postimg.org/image/91tpmtwof/  expected: combined , similar to q1, inserted one column . why do I want to combine? because I want to evaluate the percentage of sum according to prfa_ID/prfa_type...

Comment: @ will , please could you give complete code for from (entire content of query 1) as query1
join (entire content of query 2) as query2 on   => it would be useful.